# Expression to remove two similar charachers and other trailing characters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a php reg expression that removes any special character from any string and replaces the character with a hyphen. The problem is that if there are two special characters following each other, I get two hyphens. for example if I type the text `test@hhh%^` I get `test-hhh--` or if I type `test@hhh%^kkk` I get `test-hhh--kkk`. I want my expression to give me `test-hhh`. I want to remove two similar hyphens following each other plus any trailing hyphens in the string. My code is here

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', $slug);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply this regex to your string:

```
$slug = preg_replace('#-{2,}#', '-', $slug);
```

Secondly you apply a right trim (or a regular one) with a hyphen character as an extra argument.

```
$slug = trim($slug, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful info here http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, basically you need to specify a repetition modifier.